# Need an Info TWAIN and WIA Drivers to scan an Image in C#?

Tags: c#, wia, twain

I had some questions in this scanner using WIA or TWAIN in C#.net. We are planning to buy Kodak i920 Scanner to scan Image through our Application in C#. My questions are

1 . Is it possible to scan an image in single click by using any one of the drivers. ( I dont want select device dialog and image settings dialog)

2. Some scanners has inbuilt OCR functionality. can i use that OCR function programatically of that scanners. So that when i click on OCR button the scanner has to scan an do an OCR and revert me back. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: i didnt said to research anyone. If any body used this scenario, they may suggest me, that we can or not.Its a matter of yes or no, whats wrong in the question?. I feel this is not kids community to get the things only for syntax and normal C# code. If theres is no response definetely i need to research. Communities are to share , not to sink personally i feel.I know better than u that communities share Ideas and not code and i hadnot asked code in my question. Please keep in your Mind, before judging anyone, with out any proper reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.  You certainly could do all of that provided you could be certain that the same scanner was going to be available for every scan so that you could always just force use of the device you wanted.  You can also pass along the settings you'd like the device to make use of provided that the device says they're supported.  A number of SDKs either free/opensource or proprietary exist that would allow you to do that in c# -- [Atalasoft](http://atalasoft.com), [Dynamsoft](http://www.dynamsoft.com/), and [Twain.Net](http://code.google.com/p/twaindotnet/) provide one to name a few.